# How do i loop values through a post request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, post, xmlhttprequest

Hello so i am using Javascript and i want to loop values through a post request, so this is a part of my code at the moment

```
  var pid = 'B2411A07C-Q110036000'
  var body = `[{\"id\":\"e7f9dfd05f6b992d05ec8d79803ce6a6bcfb0a10972d4d9731c6b94f6ec75033\",\"variables\":{\"addToCartInput\":{\"productId\":\"",\"clientMutationId\":\"addToCartMutation\"}}}]`;
  body = JSON.parse(body);
  body[0].variables.addToCartInput.productId = pid;
  body = JSON.stringify(body)
const fetchit = await fetch(`https://www.site.de/add-to-cart/`, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: body,
```

So for single pid it works but i want it working with more pids, so that they get splitted with',' and then loops each value through the body of the request like

```
var pid = 'B2411A07C-Q110036000', 'B2411A07C-Q110036010', 'B2411A07C-Q110036020'
```

How can i do it?
I tried many things but sadly nothing worked

Comment: It depends on how server needs to receive these product ids. Could you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this with a simple `map()`

```js
let pid = ['B2411A07C-Q110036000', 'B2411A07C-Q110036010', 'B2411A07C-Q110036020']
let body = `[{\"id\":\"e7f9dfd05f6b992d05ec8d79803ce6a6bcfb0a10972d4d9731c6b94f6ec75033\",\"variables\":{\"addToCartInput\":{\"productId\":\"",\"clientMutationId\":\"addToCartMutation\"}}},{\"id\":\"e7f9dfd05f6b992d05ec8d79803ce6a6bcfb0a10972d4d9731c6b94f6ec75033\",\"variables\":{\"addToCartInput\":{\"productId\":\"",\"clientMutationId\":\"addToCartMutation\"}}},{\"id\":\"e7f9dfd05f6b992d05ec8d79803ce6a6bcfb0a10972d4d9731c6b94f6ec75033\",\"variables\":{\"addToCartInput\":{\"productId\":\"",\"clientMutationId\":\"addToCartMutation\"}}},{\"id\":\"e7f9dfd05f6b992d05ec8d79803ce6a6bcfb0a10972d4d9731c6b94f6ec75033\",\"variables\":{\"addToCartInput\":{\"productId\":\"",\"clientMutationId\":\"addToCartMutation\"}}}]`;
body = JSON.parse(body);
body = body.map((b, i) => {
  if (pid.length >= i) b.variables.addToCartInput.productId = pid[i];
  return b;
})
//body[0].variables.addToCartInput.productId = pid;
console.log(body)
body = JSON.stringify(body)
```

Comment: is it possible to build a delay in it with something like await Sleep() ?

Comment: I don't really understand why, but if you needed a delay, I would use `setTimeout()` - where do you want the delay?